# How can one change variables in a function?

Tags: functions

To be completely honest I am a litte lost.

Let us say a variable x is defined as y = 1/x. I have one function

```
f[x_]:= x^2
```

which I would like to multiply into another function

```
g[y_]:= Exp[y] + y^2 + 3 y
```

Without having to change all y into x. The way I'd do it is

```
G[y_]:= f[1/y][Exp[y] + y^2 + 3 y]
```

Is this a correct approach? Are there smarter ways to do it?

Comment: Use parentheses (`(...)`) to group expressions, not square brackets (`[...]`) - those are only for function arguments in Mathematica. Also, why not use `f[1/y]*g[y]`?

Comment: Yes I can do that. I just wanted to make sure that just putting f[1/y] inside there wouldn't cause any issues. 

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to accomplish what you want to do. Here are some.

```
f[x_] := x^2
g[y_] := Exp[y] + y^2 + 3 y
```

The simplest is probably is what Lukes suggested.

```
fg1[y_] := f[1/y] g[y]
```

or as pure function

```
fg2 = f[1/#] g[#] &;
```

However, in this case, since it is easy to define `x` as the inverse function of `y`,

```
x[y_] := 1/y
```

`Composition` ( `@*` ) can also be used.

```
fg3[y_] := (f@*x)[y] g[y]
```

or

```
fg4 = f@*x@# g@#&;
```

The last definition is a good example of the Wolfram Language's terse functional style. Some consider it elegant; others consider it obscure.

You can be satisfy yourself that all the definitions represent the same function by evaluating

```
Show[
  MapThread[
    Plot[#1[t], {t, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[#2], #3]] &, 
    {{fg1, fg2, fg3, fg4}, {17, 11, 7, 2}, {Red, Green, Orange, Black}}],
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: You seem to have forgotten a space in before `g` in the definition of `fg4`

Comment: @LukasLang. Good catch. I have made the required edit.